# integer linear recurrence and powers of two

Tags: number-theory, recurrence-relations, p-adic-number-theory

Tuesday, March 27, 2018.

This is about my alternate take on: [Solve an equation with integer variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2709676/solve-an-equation-with-integer-variables)

We have integer sequences $x_n, y_n$ with $x_0 = 0, x_1 = 16, x_2 = 552, x_3 = 18760,$ continuing
$$ x_{n+2} = 34 x_{n+1} - x_n + 8 \; \; .  $$
We also have $y_0 = 1, y_1 = 23, y_2 = 781, y_3 = 26531,$ continuing
$$ y_{n+2} = 34 y_{n+1} - y_n  \; \;  , $$
with no constant term for $y.$
The result is that we have the sequence of **even**  $x$ such that $$ 2 x^2 + x + 1 = y^2 $$

The original question asked to show that $x$ can be a power of two only for $x=16.$  My take was that the same conclusion can be realized if the 2-adic valuation of $x_n$ grows slowly. Indeed, in the two output below, when $n = 2^w,$ we see that $x_n = 2^{w+2} \cdot \mbox{ODD} \; \; .$ In the first section of output, we see that $n=2^w$ does fairly well, it does not always set a new record for the power of 2 dividing $x_n,$ but nearly so.

**QUESTION:** Can we prove a good upper bound for the power of two $e$ dividing $x_n,$ meaning $2^e \parallel x_n \; ,$ inequality suspected to be 
$$  e < n + 5   \; \; \; ?  $$  Note that many weaker inequalities will solve the original question, such as
$$  e < 3 n + 5   \; \; \; ?  $$
because this will still rule out $x_n$ being a power of 2 unless $n$ is small.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
x_{n+2} = 34 x_{n+1} - x_n + 8.   y_{n+2} = 34 y_{n+1} - y_n.
2 x^2 + x + 1 = y^2 .  y_0 = 1; y_1 = 23; y_2 = 781;
2 * 0^2 + 0 + 1 = 1  = 1^2
2 * 16^2 + 16 + 1 = 529 = 23^2
2 * 552^2 + 552 + 1 = 609961 = 781^2
------------------------------------------------

Tue Mar 27 10:46:16 PDT 2018
2   552     = 2^3 3  23
3   18760     = 2^3 5 7  67
4   637296     = 2^4 3 11 17  71
5   21649312     = 2^5 29 41  569
8   848696338272     = 2^5 3 17  cdot mbox{BIG} 
13   38394236450627331136     = 2^6 23 79  cdot mbox{BIG} 
16        = 2^6 3 11 17  cdot mbox{BIG} 
29        = 2^7  cdot mbox{BIG} 
32        = 2^7 3 17  cdot mbox{BIG} 
61        = 2^9  cdot mbox{BIG} 
128        = 2^9 3 17  cdot mbox{BIG} 
189        = 2^10 5 7^2 13^2 23 53  cdot mbox{BIG} 
256        = 2^10 3 11 17  cdot mbox{BIG} 
445        = 2^11 29 41 67  cdot mbox{BIG} 
512        = 2^11 3 17 43  cdot mbox{BIG} 
957        = 2^13 5 7 23  cdot mbox{BIG} 
2048        = 2^13 3 17 23  cdot mbox{BIG} 
3005        = 2^17 23 29 41  cdot mbox{BIG} 
32768        = 2^17 3 17 37  cdot mbox{BIG} 
35773        = 2^18  cdot mbox{BIG} 
65536        = 2^18 3 11 17  cdot mbox{BIG} 
101309        = 2^19 79  cdot mbox{BIG} 
131072        = 2^19 3 17  cdot mbox{BIG} 
232381        = 2^22  cdot mbox{BIG} 
--------------------------------------------------------------

Tue Mar 27 10:58:21 PDT 2018
2   552     = 2^3 3  23
4   637296     = 2^4 3 11 17  71
8   848696338272     = 2^5 3 17  cdot mbox{BIG} 
16        = 2^6 3 11 17  cdot mbox{BIG} 
32        = 2^7 3 17  cdot mbox{BIG} 
64        = 2^8 3 11 17  cdot mbox{BIG} 
128        = 2^9 3 17  cdot mbox{BIG} 
256        = 2^10 3 11 17  cdot mbox{BIG} 
512        = 2^11 3 17 43  cdot mbox{BIG} 
1024        = 2^12 3 11 17  cdot mbox{BIG} 
2048        = 2^13 3 17 23  cdot mbox{BIG} 
4096        = 2^14 3 11 17  cdot mbox{BIG} 
8192        = 2^15 3 17 53  cdot mbox{BIG} 
16384        = 2^16 3 11 17 71  cdot mbox{BIG} 
32768        = 2^17 3 17 37  cdot mbox{BIG} 
65536        = 2^18 3 11 17  cdot mbox{BIG} 
131072        = 2^19 3 17  cdot mbox{BIG} 
262144        = 2^20 3 11 17  cdot mbox{BIG} 
524288        = 2^21 3 17 43  cdot mbox{BIG} 
1048576        = 2^22 3 11 17  cdot mbox{BIG} 
----------------------------------------------------
```

.......................

Here is some original output, edited for clarity. $x_n = (w-1)/4, \;$ and is an integer only when $w \equiv 1,5 \pmod 8,$ then is even only when $w \equiv 1 \pmod 8 \; .$

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$  ./Pell_Target_Fundamental
  Automorphism matrix:  
    3   8
    1   3
  Automorphism backwards:  
    3   -8
    -1   3

  3^2 - 8 1^2 = 1

 w^2 - 8 v^2 = -7

Tue Mar 27 11:51:16 PDT 2018

w:  1  v:  1  SEED   KEEP +-     w mod eight:  1  x_n   =  0 =  
w:  5  v:  2  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  -1 ,  1    w mod eight:  5  x_n   =  1 =   1 
w:  11  v:  4    w mod eight:  3
w:  31  v:  11    w mod eight:  7
w:  65  v:  23    w mod eight:  1  x_n   =  16 =  2^4
w:  181  v:  64    w mod eight:  5  x_n   =  45 =  3^2 5
w:  379  v:  134    w mod eight:  3
w:  1055  v:  373    w mod eight:  7
w:  2209  v:  781    w mod eight:  1  x_n   =  552 =  2^3 3 23
w:  6149  v:  2174    w mod eight:  5  x_n   =  1537 =  29 53
w:  12875  v:  4552    w mod eight:  3
w:  35839  v:  12671    w mod eight:  7
w:  75041  v:  26531    w mod eight:  1  x_n   =  18760 =  2^3 5 7 67
w:  208885  v:  73852    w mod eight:  5  x_n   =  52221 =  3 13^2 103
w:  437371  v:  154634    w mod eight:  3
w:  1217471  v:  430441    w mod eight:  7
w:  2549185  v:  901273    w mod eight:  1  x_n   =  637296 =  2^4 3 11 17 71
w:  7095941  v:  2508794    w mod eight:  5  x_n   =  1773985 =  5 197 1801
w:  14857739  v:  5253004    w mod eight:  3
w:  41358175  v:  14622323    w mod eight:  7
w:  86597249  v:  30616751    w mod eight:  1  x_n   =  21649312 =  2^5 29 41 569
w:  241053109  v:  85225144    w mod eight:  5  x_n   =  60263277 =  3 3499 5741
w:  504725755  v:  178447502    w mod eight:  3

Tue Mar 27 12:00:17 PDT 2018

 w^2 - 8 v^2 = -7

jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ 
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$
```